# Usage of sed in shell

Tags: shell, sed

I need to use `sed` in shell to do the following things in a file:

1) Suppose I have a line:

```
#listen_tcp = 1
```

I want to delete first character `#`

2) Suppose I have a line:

```
#listen_tcp = 1
```

I want to change to last character `1` to `0`

3) Suppose I have a line:

```
#listen_tcp
```

I want to append it, to `#listen_tcp = 1`

4) Suppose I have a line:

```
libvirtd_opts="-d"
```

I want to insert something, to `libvirtd_opts="-d -l"`

5) Suppose I have a line:

```
tcp_port = "16059"
```

I just want to change it, to `tcp_port = "16509"`

How can I use `sed` to do all of them in a text file? I only know how to relace it with a whole line. For example, I will open the file and remember the line of the words, then use `sed s/a/b/g` to replace a with b. That's my best knowledge, I wonder if there is better way to achieve this? For instance, search the line by keywords and replace part of this line?

Comment: I only know how to relace it with a whole line. I wonder if there is a graceful way?

Comment: @user2886717, `only know how to replace it with a whole line`. Can you show what do you know?

Comment: re-edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1)

```
echo "#listen_tcp = 1" | sed '/listen/s/#//g'
listen_tcp = 1
```

For 2)

```
echo "#listen_tcp = 1" | sed '/listen/s/1/0/g'
#listen_tcp = 0
```

For 3)

```
echo "#listen_tcp" | sed 's/#listen_tcp/& = 1/g'
#listen_tcp = 1
```

For 4)

```
echo 'libvirtd_opts="-d"' | sed 's/libvirtd_opts="-d/& -l/g'
libvirtd_opts="-d -l"
```

For 5)

```
echo 'tcp_port = "16059"' | sed '/tcp_port/s/16059/16509/g'
tcp_port = "16509"
```

Comment: I find I can do the same thing if I remove `listen` in /listen/s/1/0/g, what's the special usage of `listen` here?

Comment: I do not understand what you like to do. Post input and output example.

Comment: Then post and example file and what you like to get out of it in one go.  (This may be a new question)

Comment: @user2886717: `/listen/` in `1)` and `2)` is a so-called _context address_ and selects via a regex what lines the following `s` command is to be applied to (here, all lines containing `listen`). In the case at hand - with only 1 input line that should be processed unconditionally - it is not needed.